# vs code intellisense does not work when require has anything other than a string literal

Tags: node.js, visual-studio-code, intellisense

I would really like intellisense to work on VS Code and it does if I choose a string literal for the module I wish to require. For eg:

```
// When using this, intellisense works
const myLib = require("../../MyLibraries/myLibrary.js");
```

When I use this, intellisense does not work

```
const pathToLib = "../../MyLibraries";
const myLib = require(`${pathToLib}/myLibrary.js`);
```

Or when I use this, intellisense still does not work.

```
function requireFromLib(file) {
    return require(`../../MyLibraries/${file}`);
}

const logger = requireFromLib('myLibrary.js');
```

This last option was recommended by ChatGPT and it also said to restart Typescript if this fails. I have tried them both and it still does not work.

I have also tried process.env. and that fails too.

I can use string literal, but I have a lot of modules from my library that I include from time to time and using a base path to the Library's folder makes it easier to make changes. Any advice on how to get intellisense to work?

Comment: [vscode-node-module-intellisense](https://github.com/leizongmin/vscode-node-module-intellisense) I think an extension like this one is what you're looking for? Note that installing third-party extensions can be risky.

Comment: Thank you, @Magic1647. I will play around with it and see if this works for my needs and weigh the pros and cons coz I feel the same way as you about 3rd party extensions.

Comment: Thanks @starball. That does answer the question. It doesn't solve my problem, but it does confirm that a solution to this does not exist at this time.